# Mysql: join table by two the same column values

Tags: mysql

post can have many categories.
I need to find posts that have two categories with ID 1 and 2.

It is possible do query with one join?
My solution:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post p
INNER JOIN category c ON 
c.post_id = p.id
INNER JOIN category cf ON 
cf.post_id = p.id
WHERE c.id = "1" AND cf.id = "2"
```

It's working, but maybe can optimize?

Comment: I have done this already... Lemme get it for you...

Answer (score 0):

Why you need two joins

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post p
INNER JOIN category c ON 
c.post_id = p.id
WHERE c.id = "1" or c.id = "2"
```

Comment: Thanks, but post must have both categories.